# infinite inner arrays with push() method in javascript chrome console

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome-console

Recently i was experimenting with array `push()` method in javascript. 
I created an array, and pushed the same array using push method.

```
var a=['hello', 4]

a.push(a)
```

the result was surprising, when i explored the array items in chrome console, there was infinite array produced. i want to know why this is happening. As the `push()` method adds the element on last.

I was expecting this result

```
['hello, 4, ['hello',4]]
```

but the result was something else, here is the screenshot of chrome console
[problem screenshot, infinite inner arrays using push method in JavaScript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrOvE.jpg)

Comment: Try: `a.push([...a])`

Comment: Hi anlijudavid, can you please elaborate how this code works, i am confused with "... " notation before array name

Comment: @Diwakar I explain usage of anlijudavid comment in my answer you can check it.

Comment: I want to know usage of this notation: [...a]

Comment: `...` = Destructuring (https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/)

`a.push([...a])` is equivalent to copy all objects of `a` and then `push` to `a` object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you assign an object to a variable in Javascript (and indeed in most similar languages), that variable holds what is called a "reference" to that object. Note that arrays in JS are objects, but primitive values like strings and numbers are not.

One consequence of object assignments being "by reference" is that any change you make to that object - even if its done to another variable that happens to reference the same object - will "show up" when you inspect the original variable.

So here, you start off with

```
var a=['hello', 4]
```

And then do

```
a.push(a)
```

then the object (array) to which `a` points has been changed. It now has an additional element on the end - which is `a`, the very same array we're talking about.

So it expands recursively:

```
a = ['hello', 4, a]
  = ['hello', 4, ['hello', 4, a]]
  = ['hello', 4, ['hello', 4, ['hello', 4, a]]]
   ...
```

And so on, infinitely. This doesn't require an infinite amount of memory, because the third element of the array is simply a reference to the memory location which holds the array.

Comment: But if I keep inspecting the array furthermore will it require more memory to show the array ? or does just print it out without anything saved in memory?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how the browser console representation of such values works (it likely differs in different browsers), but of course, in theory at least, the more you expand it the more memory you'd need to hold everything you can see. I don't really see it being a practical problem though.